# Possible to reverse the layering of items in an unordered list using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a collection of items in an unordered list that overlap each other.  My issue is that I need the first item to have the highest z-index and then go down from there.  I can do this manually by setting the z-index:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp9YD/7/

But I would like to do this without manually setting each z-index (not sure if this is possible).  Right now If i don't use the z-index it renders like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp9YD/8/

With items that come later in the list being on top which is what I would expect.  Is there a way that I can get it to render like the first example without manually specifying the z-index or using javascript?

Comment: I tried hacking together some kind of solution that made use of the very under-used/not-well-known `counter-` properties in CSS, but had no success. I think this would require Javascript, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried too. :> But counters can be used only with "content" property. :|

Comment: Darn, I didn't bother checking the spec, and had assumed they were more global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have needed to do something similar in the past. I solved it be floating all li's to the right and listing them in reverse order.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/KfK9w/

Comment: Visually, this works, but the drawback is that semantically (especially for screen readers), this wreaks havoc with the HTML.

Comment: Well it depends, it is being used on an unordered list after all.

Comment: @thirtydot It took me a while to figure too when I had a similar issue. It's not really intuitive so our brains don't naturally think about this kind of solution.

Comment: @joshuanhibbert: Yeah. Though I did manage to think of `transform: scaleX(-1)` in the now deleted comment. Oh well.